# Variable sized dereferencing in c

Tags: c, pointers, casting, embedded

I have a Destination pointer stored in `void* DestPointer` and a source pointer stored in `void* SrcPointer`. Assume the destination pointer, points to starting adress of the free and safe memory and source pointer points to the starting adress of memory containing data it's type may be int16_t or int32_t) but can be interfered with counter `i`. Now I want to fill the memory by :

```
*(uint16_t*)DestPointer=*(uint16_t*) SrcPointer
```

I want this uint8_t change according to i, it could be a bounus if the stated problem generalizer to something like.

```
i==-1 -> int8_t
i==-2 -> int16_t
i==-4 -> int32_t
i==1 -> uint8_t
i==2 -> uint16_t
i==4 -> uint32_t
```

How to implement it? I just know enumeration can't work maybe some macro or magical c expression help.

It seems I need to implement memcpy() in a specific way!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242669/discussion-on-question-by-mohammadsdtmnd-variable-sized-dereferencing-in-c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those strange indices aren't very helpful - it would have been much easier with adjacent numbers 0,1,2... So the best thing to do is to get rid of those negative numbers. Another good option would be to pick the copy size based on type with `_Generic`.

---

Otherwise assuming you can't change those index numbers... When dealing with bad interfaces that you are stuck with and can't change, X-macros might often be an ok solution. Something like this:

```
#define INT_TYPES(X)       \
/*  type      val  */      \
  X(int8_t,   -1)          \
  X(int16_t,  -2)          \
  X(int32_t,  -4)          \
  X(uint8_t,   1)          \
  X(uint16_t,  2)          \
  X(uint32_t,  4)          \
```

Then create an enum `eint8_t = -1`, `eint16_t = -2` and so on:

```
typedef enum
{
  #define INT_TYPE_ENUM(type, val) e##type = (val),
  INT_TYPES(INT_TYPE_ENUM)
} int_t;
```

Then a look-up table to compensate for the negative indices. This is using designated initializers so we get for example index `[4 + -4] = sizeof(int32_t)`:

```
#define lookup_offset 4
const size_t int_type_lookup[] = 
{
  #define INT_TYPE_SIZE(type, val) [lookup_offset+(val)] = sizeof(type),
  INT_TYPES(INT_TYPE_SIZE)
};
```

(Similarly you could make a function pointer look-up table which might be handy in some cases.)

The copy function which is a wrapper around `memcpy`:

```
void intcpy (void* restrict dst, 
             const void* restrict src, 
             size_t n, 
             int_t type)
{
  memcpy(dst,src, n*int_type_lookup[lookup_offset + type]);
}
```

Complete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

#define INT_TYPES(X)       \
/*  type      val  */      \
  X(int8_t,   -1)          \
  X(int16_t,  -2)          \
  X(int32_t,  -4)          \
  X(uint8_t,   1)          \
  X(uint16_t,  2)          \
  X(uint32_t,  4)          \

typedef enum
{
  #define INT_TYPE_ENUM(type, val) e##type = (val),
  INT_TYPES(INT_TYPE_ENUM)
} int_t;

void intcpy (void* restrict dst, 
             const void* restrict src, 
             size_t n, 
             int_t type)
{
  #define lookup_offset 4
  const size_t int_type_lookup[] = 
  {
    #define INT_TYPE_SIZE(type, val) [lookup_offset+(val)] = sizeof(type),
    INT_TYPES(INT_TYPE_SIZE)
  };
  memcpy(dst,src, n*int_type_lookup[lookup_offset + type]);
}

int main (void)
{
  int16_t some_data [50]={1,2,3,4,5};
  int16_t dst[50];
  intcpy(dst, some_data, 50, eint16_t);

  for(size_t i=0; i<5; i++)
  {
    printf("%d ", (int)dst[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thx, Little description about _generic C11 could be helpful, please. I think this kind of macro usage is not allowed in C99? Note my preference to is to automate according to i, the first line on code I've written in question, not the memcpy().

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd This code is fine from C99 to standard C17.

Comment: Ty, But what about memcpy()less code?

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd "source pointer point to the memory with occupied data with not constant element length" Isn't this more than 1 element?

Comment: I mean maybe it's int32_t or int16_t. Then according to pointer adress the data to be copied, may be 32bit width or 16 bit width. Also the question updated.